# What is the current Crashlytics version?

Tags: android, crashlytics

This line is automatically generated by Gradle. I want to avoid using `+`, so I need the most recent stable version of Crashlytics.

```
compile "com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+"
```

Comment: You're not using the Fabric version of Crashlytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`, and look for `com.crashlytics.android/crashlytics`. In there you will find folders with cached versions of the dependency, which are named with the full version number.

My latest cached version is `1.1.13`, but it might be outdated already. Note that the gradle plugin has a different version number.

Comment: The question is asking for "the most recent stable version of Crashlytics." This gives you the current version installed on your machine, which is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 4):

get the latest version from maven metadata:

https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/maven-metadata.xml

.. same with the fabric plugin:

https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 0):

Before version `2.3.0`, we can find the latest release from https://maven.fabric.io, we can get the xml output of all the release version without download to local.

```
$ curl -L https://maven.fabric.io |tidy -xml -i - |grep "crashlytics\-.*pom<"
```

After version `2.3.0`, no xml output anymore when accessing the url above. 
Or we should change the way to get xml output?

But we can get latest version from its docs, assuming crashlytics documents are updated, it's version `2.6.5` when writing this post.

The pom file did exists https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.5/crashlytics-2.6.5.pom

Answer (score 0):

The most recent Crashlytics version (for Android) is listed here:
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Also, make sure to keep the Gradle plugin up to date by checking this link for the latest version: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin